# How to upload a file to the server in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I want to send a file to server in iPhone.  Is there any iPhone API to implement that functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) is a wrapper around the network APIs and makes it very easy to upload a file. 
Here's their example (but you can do this on the iPhone too - save images to "disk" and later upload them.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Comment: I second this opinion - ASIHTTPRequest is a good wrapper to be used in this sittuation.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial will let you upload files to server](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/)

Comment: This solution is adequate for small posts only as it stores the complete post in the memory until it is sent. If this is not a possibility then the the ASIHTTPRequest wrapper could be used instead.