# How to upload a file to server from an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, file-upload

i have copied all address book contacts to an array and write it to a plist(xml file) file in applications documents directory. how can i upload this file to a web server?
please give me some reference about this topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar question:
[File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)

Code:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://yourserver.com/upload.php";
NSString *filename = @"filename";
request= [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:YOUR_NSDATA_HERE]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(returnString);
```

Comment: where does this code is taking the pah of my file? and what is boundary? i don't understand it. please explain the code...

Comment: [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:YOUR_NSDATA_HERE]];
Instead of "YOUR_NSDATA_HERE" put "[NSData dataWithContentOfFile:@"path/to/file"]"

The code is not from me, follow my link to get more infos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try following links in which you can find your answer
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130969/how-send-file-txt-xml-from-iphone-to-serverweb-or-email)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465361/how-to-upload-the-file-to-server-in-iphone-sdk)
[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674751/how-to-call-a-webservice-from-an-iphone-app)