# uploading a file from iphone to server

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload a file to the server in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465361/how-to-upload-a-file-to-the-server-in-iphone-sdk)

hi

i am a beginner in iphone applications i want to make an application for transfering a file from iphone to server to later print it .how can i perform it can anyone tell me the code for this .

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface printerapplicationAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UILabel *display;
    UILabel *display1;

    IBOutlet UIButton *print;
    IBOutlet UIButton *cancel;

    IBOutlet UITextField *addres;
    IBOutlet UITextField *name; 
}

-(IBAction) print: (id) sender;
-(IBAction) cancel: (id) sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *display;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *display1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *address;

@end
```

Comment: You are asking for file-upload to a server but you are providing an example header file showing some basic actions and properties which are just remotely connected to your question. Have you actually done a search on SO for [iPhone file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+file+upload)?